# which ports are needed for ROS?

Tags: ros, wifi, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I need to run ROS in a host wifi network and I do not have full control over it. I saw there is a firewall that prevents connections between clients to port 11311, that seems to me to be the port roscore listens to incoming connections. Are there other ports that need to be open? If I find a way to tunnel 11311 to port 80 (that is open) would I succeed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198150/which-ports-are-needed-for-ros?/) by [madmage](https://answers.ros.org/users/11946/madmage/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2014-11-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS master uses port 11311 by default; you can change this by passing the --port option to roscore and by setting a different port in your ROS_MASTER_URI. Note that ports below 1024 usually require root privileges.

Each ROS node sets up a few listening TCP sockets on random ports, one to service xmlrpc calls from the ROS master and other nodes, and one or several for topic connections and services. These ports are randomly allocated by the OS, so it's not possible to know what they will be ahead of time.

I would start by figuring out which ports you actually have available between clients, and then maybe look into some of the multimaster packages or rosbridge for bridging topics between separate ROS masters running on each client.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2